# how to raise salary depending on hiredate in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select ename, hiredate, sal,
decode(hiredate, 1980, sal*1.3, 1981, sal*1.1, 1982, sal*1.2,0) as bonus
from emp;
```

i have to print ename, hiredate, sal, bonus

if the hiredate is 1980, then the bonus should print sal raised by 30%

if the hiredate is 1981, sal raised by 10%

if the hiredate is 1820, sal raised by 20%

else 0

how should i fix it?

Comment: If you had something that you tried and it did not work and it needed fixing, you would have come to the right place: that's what we do here on Stackoverflow.  But what you appear to have is not something that needs fixing, but homework instead. And we are not into doing that for you here.

Comment: This is the typical interview and/or exam question for which there are thousands of existing propositions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use `decode()`.  It is obsolete.  The SQL standard is `case`.  Second, you need to deal with *dates*; they don't magically become years:

```
select ename, hiredate, sal,
       (case when extract(year from hiredate) = 1980
             then sal * 0.3
             when extract(year from hiredate) = 1981
             then sal * 0.1
             when extract(year from hiredate) = 1982
             then sal * 0.2
             else 0
        end) as bonus
from emp;
```

I also assume the purpose is to show the increment in the salary, not the total.  It seems unreasonable to set total compensation to everyone not hired in 1980, 1981, or 1982 to 0.